# Tooltip over a Polygon in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, tooltip, google-maps-api-3

I have polygons for various region and states in my application. Markers implement tooltip by taking the title attribute. On mouseover and mouseout over a polygon events can be fired. How do I create a tooltip that looks like the tooltip that is implemented for a marker.

Edit-1: Adding the code used to create the polygon and attach the handlers to show/hide tooltips.

```
function addPolygon(points) {
    var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: points,
        strokeColor: " #FFFFFF",
        strokeOpacity: 0.15,
        strokeWeight: 1.5,
        fillColor: "#99ff66",
        fillOpacity: 0.14
    });
    var tooltip = document.createElement('div');
    tooltip.innerHTML = "Alok";

    google.maps.event.addListener(polygon,'mouseover',function(){
        tooltip.style.visibility = 'visible';
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(polygon,'mouseout',function(){
        tooltip.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    });
    polygon.setMap(map);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google maps v3 polyline tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112867/google-maps-v3-polyline-tooltip)

Comment: Not a duplicate, this is the older question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will have to do it yourself.In a page i have implemented i attached a mouse move event to the page so i can record the mouse position.Then when a polygon mouseover event occurs i display a custom div near the mouse position

[image: Polygon tooltip]

Hope it helps

Comment: I did try something like this. My approach when as follows: 
1. I have the mouseover and mouseout events.
2. I created a div and showed it in the mouserover event and hid it in the mouseout event.

This did not work for me.

Comment: Maybe if you post your code we can understand where the error came from.

Comment: Try to place a div inside the html and not create it dynamically.Also try to use css---->display:none

Comment: Followed both the steps. Strangely I dont even get a js error. Kept a static div in a page and made the div to show up on mouseover of polygon, but dint see any changes.

Comment: I suggest to try to get a separate mini project just to test the div hide-show just to be sure you do everything the right way and then try to attach the tested code to your main project

Answer (score 5):

There's actually a neat trick to work around this (strange) limitation in Google Maps. When moving your mouse over a data item, you can just add a tooltip to the map's `<div>`. It will be added at the location where your mouse pointer currently is - right over the item!

```
map.data.addListener('mouseover', mouseOverDataItem);
map.data.addListener('mouseout', mouseOutOfDataItem);
```

...

```
function mouseOverDataItem(mouseEvent) {
  const titleText = mouseEvent.feature.getProperty('propContainingTooltipText');

  if (titleText) {
    map.getDiv().setAttribute('title', titleText);
  }
}

function mouseOutOfDataItem(mouseEvent) {
  map.getDiv().removeAttribute('title');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me:
googleShape - is your polygon or circle or rectangle.
titleText - message you need to post on hover of shapes.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(googleshape, 'mouseover', function() {
    this.map.getDiv().setAttribute('title', "`titleText`");
});
google.maps.event.addListener(googleshape, 'mouseout', function() {
    this.map.getDiv().removeAttribute('title');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following

```
//Add a listener for the click event
google.maps.event.addListener('click', showArrays);
infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
```

then when the click event happens call the following function

```
function showArrays(event) {

  var contentString = 'Content here';

  // Replace the info window's content and position.
  infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
  infoWindow.setPosition(event.latLng);

  infoWindow.open(map);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A nice solution will be to use Google's built in `InfoWindow` as a tooltip/popup container. Then listen to `mouseover` and `mouseout` to show/hide the tooltip.

Notice that by using `InfoWindow` you can also put HTML markup as the content of the tooltip and not only plain text.

```
const mapHandler: google.maps.Map = ... // your code here
const polygon: google.maps.Polygon = ... // your colde here

const popUp = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: "<span style='color:red'> SOME MESSAGE </span>" // red message
});

polygon.addListener("mouseover", (event) => {
  popUp.setPosition(event.latLng);
  popUp.open(mapHandler);
});

polygon.addListener("mouseout", (event) => {
  popUp.close()
});
```

[image: result map image]