# Google maps v3 polyline tooltip

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

A google maps marker object (google.maps.Marker) has a title property, so when a user moves their mouse over the marker a simple tooltip is displayed.

There isn't a title property on a polyline (google.maps.Polyline). Is there a way I can do this / simulate this in V3? <strike>I could do this in V2</strike>, and I can't find an example for V3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i'm not mistaken i don't think it is possible to set the tooltip since as you mentioned there is not a title property in PolygonOptions object.But you can **make a div** that looks exactly the same as the tooltip and place it let's say in the tip of your mouse **during the mousemove event**.I tried also to find a solution to place this tooltip somewhere in the center of the polygon but i think it is too much of a trouble that's why i also think the google guys didn't implement it also.
Cheers

Answer (score 13):

I combined @samshull's answer above (duly upvoted!) with info from [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events?csw=1#EventArguments) to make the [InfoWindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#InfoWindow) appear where the user's cursor mouses over the line:

```
// Open the InfoWindow on mouseover:
google.maps.event.addListener(line, 'mouseover', function(e) {
   infoWindow.setPosition(e.latLng);
   infoWindow.setContent("You are at " + e.latLng);
   infoWindow.open(map);
});

// Close the InfoWindow on mouseout:
google.maps.event.addListener(line, 'mouseout', function() {
   infoWindow.close();
});
```

Here, `line` is your [PolyLine](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Polyline) object; `map` is your [Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#Map) object; and `infoWindow` is your InfoWindow object, which I just create with:

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
```

I also follow [this advice](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows#add) by re-using the same InfoWindow object for all my polylines rather than creating a new one for each line:

> Best practices: For the best user experience, only one info window
>   should be open on the map at any one time. Multiple info windows make
>   the map appear cluttered. If you only need one info window at a time,
>   you can create just one InfoWindow object and open it at different
>   locations or markers upon map events, such as user clicks. If you do
>   need more than one info window, you can display multiple InfoWindow
>   objects at the same time.

Note that `infoWindow.setContent()` takes a string. So call `toString()` on a number variable if you want to display a number in the InfoWindow.

I view all of this as an imperfect workaround until Google Maps hopefully one day add a `title` property to [PolylineOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PolylineOptions), just like they've already done for [MarkerOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions).

Answer (score 7):

I am not 100% this is the only way, or the best way, but it is **a** way to create a window over your Polyline

In Google maps V3, you should to create an [InfoWindow](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#InfoWindow) then set the content using `myInfoWindow.setContent("Hello World!")`

In order to make it show on mouseover, you will need to do something like:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(myPolyline, 'mouseover', function() {
    myInfoWindow.open(mymap);
    // mymap represents the map you created using google.maps.Map
});

// assuming you want the InfoWindow to close on mouseout
google.maps.event.addListener(myPolyline, 'mouseout', function() {
    myInfoWindow.close();
});
```

Comment: I'm already using an infowindow for the full details, so this wouldn't work.

Comment: But how to position info window on polyline?

Comment: @Naman: See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events?csw=1#EventArguments for how to capture the cursor position and my answer below for details.

Answer (score 4):

I found this online that helped me do tooltips on polygons,
from http://philmap.000space.com/gmap-api/poly-hov.html:

```
var tooltip=function(){
var id = 'tt';
var top = 3;
var left = 3;
var maxw = 200;
var speed = 10;
var timer = 20;
var endalpha = 95;
var alpha = 0;
var tt,t,c,b,h;
var ie = document.all ? true : false;
return{
    show:function(v,w){         
        if(tt == null){             
            tt = document.createElement('div');
            tt.setAttribute('id',id);
            t = document.createElement('div');
            t.setAttribute('id',id + 'top');
            c = document.createElement('div');
            c.setAttribute('id',id + 'cont');
            b = document.createElement('div');
            b.setAttribute('id',id + 'bot');
            tt.appendChild(t);
            tt.appendChild(c);
            tt.appendChild(b);
            document.body.appendChild(tt);              
            tt.style.opacity = 0;
            tt.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=0)';
            document.onmousemove = this.pos;                
        }
        tt.style.visibility = 'visible';
        tt.style.display = 'block';
        c.innerHTML = v;
        tt.style.width = w ? w + 'px' : 'auto';
        if(!w && ie){
            t.style.display = 'none';
            b.style.display = 'none';
            tt.style.width = tt.offsetWidth;
            t.style.display = 'block';
            b.style.display = 'block';
        }
        if(tt.offsetWidth > maxw){tt.style.width = maxw + 'px'}
        h = parseInt(tt.offsetHeight) + top;
        clearInterval(tt.timer);
        tt.timer = setInterval(function(){tooltip.fade(1)},timer);
    },
    pos:function(e){
        var u = ie ? event.clientY + document.documentElement.scrollTop : e.pageY;
        var l = ie ? event.clientX + document.documentElement.scrollLeft : e.pageX;
        tt.style.top = (u - h) + 'px';
        tt.style.left = (l + left) + 'px';
    },
    fade:function(d){
        var a = alpha;
        if((a != endalpha && d == 1) || (a != 0 && d == -1)){
            var i = speed;
            if(endalpha - a < speed && d == 1){
                i = endalpha - a;
            }else if(alpha < speed && d == -1){
                i = a;
            }
            alpha = a + (i * d);
            tt.style.opacity = alpha * .01;
            tt.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + alpha + ')';
        }else{
            clearInterval(tt.timer);
            if(d == -1){tt.style.display = 'none'}
        }
    },
    hide:function(){
        clearInterval(tt.timer);
        tt.timer = setInterval(function(){tooltip.fade(-1)},timer);
    }
};
}();
```

Also, Please see this SO discussion about the same topic:
[Tooltip over a Polygon in Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302300/tooltip-over-a-polygon-in-google-maps)
And,
[Google maps rectangle/polygon with title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10102470/google-maps-rectangle-polygon-with-title/10122393#10122393)

Comment: Tool tip not working in fullscreen mode. any solution to fix that.