# Add Tooltip on a data.feature object like we can do for the marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, tooltip

I work on a Google maps API project and I want to show tooltips when the pointer is hovering over the features. It's very easy when you work with markers : you just need to feed a "title" in the marker's options ([see this exemple](http://bescu.github.io/GoogleMapsApiTest/tooltipMarkerExemple.html)) but I work with data.feature object and I don't find how to do this?

I would continue to work why data.feature objects because it's easier to manage differents layers.

```
function elemOver(event){
    console.log(event.feature.getProperty("Libelle")); // I put a console.log to test the listener but I don't know how to do to add a tooltip
};

function elemOut(event){
    console.log (event.feature.getProperty("Libelle")," out"); // I put a console.log to test the listener but I don't know how to do to add a tooltip
};

data = new google.maps.Data();
data.loadGeoJson('layer.geojson');
data.setMap(map);
data.addListener('mouseover',elemOver);
data.addListener('mouseout',elemOut);
```

You can see my work here : http://bescu.github.io/GoogleMapsApiTest/

Thank you,

Maxime

Comment: Add mouseover/mouseout listeners to map.data like [this example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-data-dynamic) in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer#change_appearance_dynamically).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I added theses listeners but I don't find what object or function I could use to obtain the same result than the first exemple with a marker on my first post. In your link, the function is changing the style of the features.

Comment: I don't see any code in your question.

Comment: Sorry, you're right it wasn't clear enough, I just added a piece of my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `setStyle` with a function as argument:

When you use it with a function as argument you be able to set a style(e.g. `title`) based on a property of the feature(e.g. `Libelle`)

```
   map.data.setStyle(function(feature){
    return {
      title:feature.getProperty('Libelle')||null
      //more styles    
    };
 });
```

Demo:
[**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/L58aprhf/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/L58aprhf/)

Comment: Thank you very much, It's perfect! I'm sorry that I can't vote for the answer because I don't have enough reputation but I've accepted your answer.

Comment: Strange. This doesn't seem to work (anymore) ? Also, the docs explicitly mention it only works for points: "Rollover text. Only applies to point geometries."

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Data.StyleOptions

Comment: Updating my 5 year old comment: It works (again) now - indeed only for geometries of type 'point' :). For non-point geometries, have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302300/tooltip-over-a-polygon-in-google-maps/47818570#47818570 / Funny side note; I actually just encountered this answer and this comment, read it and was about to answer on it, without realizing it was my own :').

Answer (score 2):

Since the `title` property only works for point-type features it does not help for things like polygons.

I am therefore using an `InfoWindow` to show a similar tooltip-type label when the user clicks on the polygon like so:

```
    map.data.addListener('click', function (event) {
    if (areaInfoWindow != null) {
        areaInfoWindow.close();
        areaInfoWindow = null;
    }
    areaInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: event.feature.getProperty('name'),
        position: event.latLng
    });
    areaInfoWindow.open(map);
});
```

And this could be relatively easily modified to show and hide the info-window on `mouseover` and `mouseout` events respectively, though I'm not so sure that it would look all that great...

I suppose you could also not use an InfoWindow but instead use some other custom HTML element -- a custom DIV? -- instead.